# Cannot access forwarded port on container from other containers in Docker network

Tags: mysql, docker, ssh

Cannot access forwarded port on container from other containers in Docker network

On the Docker container A executed command to open the ssh tunnel to forward 3306 port from remote MySQL server to container.

```
ssh -4 -NL 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 "${SSH_USER}@${MONOLITH_IP}"
```

It's accesible from inside container A.

```
telnet 127.0.0.1:3306
Connected to 127.0.0.1:3306
```

```
netstat -lnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

But it's not accessible from container B

```
telnet A 3306
telnet: can't connect to remote host (172.17.0.5): Connection refused
```

Both container inside same network and running on alpine image.

Commands:

- `ssh -4 -NL 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 "${SSH_USER}@${MONOLITH_IP}"` (on container A)
- `telnet 127.0.0.1:3306` (on container A)
- `telnet A:3306`  (on container B)

Expectation:

Successful connection from container B to the forwarded port on container A (MySQL server).

Actual Result:

`telnet A:3306` (on container B) returns `telnet: can't connect to remote host (172.17.0.5): Connection refused`

despite verifying network connectivity, port availability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSH tunnel is bound to the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) inside container A, which means it is only accessible from within that container.

To make the forwarded port accessible to other containers within the same Docker network, binding the SSH tunnel to the container's IP address or 0.0.0.0 (all network interfaces) instead of 127.0.0.1.

```
ssh -4 -NL 0.0.0.0:3306:127.0.0.1:3306 "${SSH_USER}@${MONOLITH_IP}"
```

Comment: Nice! If you see a check mark by your answer, you should click it and mark your answer as accepted. That'll allow others to see that this issue is resolved.